# Connecting two interfaces

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet

I’ve got 2 network interfaces, `wlan0` and `tun_nrf24`. `wlan0` is reachable from my LAN network so, I can connect to it. I need to make `tun_nrf24` to available from my LAN too.

- gateway: `192.168.1.1` (default)
- wlan0: `192.168.1.8`
- tun_nrf24: `192.168.3.2`

`tun_nrf24` is interface where some devices are connected and I would like to connect them with my `wlan0` network to download some data from this devices.

I can ping `tun_nrf24` and devices connected to this network (eg `192.168.3.4`) from device `192.168.1.8` but can't do the same from laptop connected to router (network `192.168.1.x`)

Should I use NAT to be able to connect to ping this device? If yes, how to set it properly?

Should I change something in my router configuration?

My topology looks like this; my router is a [TP-LINK TL-WR940N](http://www.tp-link.com/lk/products/details/?model=TL-WR940N):

```
Laptop <-> (192.168.1.x) Router <-> (192.168.1.x) Device <~>(192.168.3.x) Device_1
```

`ip route show` says:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.8
192.168.3.0/24 dev tun_nrf24 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.3.2
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set in Advanced Routing table static routing list with such a settings:

```
Destination network Subnet Mask     Default Gateway
192.168.3.0         255.255.255.0   192.168.1.8 (device)
```

Ofc I did that in my home router settings. So now, my router know that when i'm trying to connect 192.168.3.*, packets should be send to 192.168.1.8 and there on my device there is performing NATing (I think it is^^)